# Plot in Asymptote. help to check my code here

Tags: pgfplots, floats, asymptote

I want to plot $4x^2+4y^2-z^2=0$
Here my code please help to check

```
    import graph3;
currentprojection=orthographic(5,4,4);
size3(100);
triple f(pair t){return (1\2*sin(t.y)*cos(t.x), 1\2*sin(t.y)*sin(t.
x), -1*cos(t.y));}
surface s=surface(f,(pi,0) ,(2*pi,pi),nu=40,nv=40,Spline);
draw(s,green+opacity(0.9),render(merge=true));
xaxis3(Label("$x$"),p=blue ,Arrow3);
yaxis3(Label("$y$"),p=blue ,Arrow3);
zaxis3(Label("$z$"),p=blue ,Arrow3);
```

But I[image: Using geogebra] want to draw like this

Comment: If I use your components I get `4*(1\2*sin(t.y)*cos(t.x))^2+4*(1\2*sin(t.y)*sin(t.x))^2-(cos(t.y))^2=(sin(t.y))^2-(cos(t.y))^2`, which is not zero. Try replacing `cos(t.y)` by `sin(t.y)` in the last component (if you need to make this a spherical coordinate, which I do not see a real motivation for).

Comment: or Do you have any code different from this for me ?:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not really asymptote-savy, but your input does not satisfy

```
4x^2+4y^2-z^2=0
```

so I changed it to something that does.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
import graph3;
currentprojection=orthographic(5,4,4);
size3(100);
triple f(pair t){return (t.y*cos(t.x)/2,t.y*sin(t.x)/2, t.y);}
surface s=surface(f,(0,-1) ,(2*pi,3),nu=40,nv=40,Spline);
draw(s,green+opacity(0.9),render(merge=true));
xaxis3(Label("$x$"),p=blue ,Arrow3);
yaxis3(Label("$y$"),p=blue ,Arrow3);
zaxis3(Label("$z$"),p=blue ,Arrow3);
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Not too bad, given that I do not really know what I am doing here.

Update. Compile at http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/

```
import graph3;
currentprojection=orthographic(1,1,1);
size(10cm);
triple f(pair t){return (t.y*cos(t.x)/2,t.y*sin(t.x)/2, t.y);}
surface s=surface(f,(0,-2) ,(2*pi,2),Spline);
draw(s,cyan+opacity(0.9),blue+0.6bp,render(merge=true));
xaxis3(Label("$x$"),Arrow3);
yaxis3(Label("$y$"),Arrow3);
zaxis3(Label("$z$"),Arrow3);
```

[image]

Comment: I can not write an answer, I will update your answer.

Comment: @NguyenVanJustonlyChi Thanks! But why can't you write an answer?

Comment: I simply don't like to write. :-)

Comment: @NguyenVanJustonlyChi Understandable... ;-)

Comment: @NguyenVanJustonlyChi, Yeah really thank so much if my eqaution like this how can I change? With this equation $4x^2+4y^2-z^2=1$. Do you have any explaination about how to write code in this kind of function?

Comment: @PetterGreen For the first question, you should ask `user230864`, his will help you if possible. For the second question, the equation $4x^2+4y^2-z^2=1$ is belong to quaratic surface. Drawing this kind of surface is easy if you have its parametric equation, very difficult (specially for 3D) if you only have its implicit equation.

Comment: @PetterGreen See examples at the official asymptote site, rewrite it and check it. You need refer more and more documentation about its mathematical knowledge. Anyone can help you if you show what you try so far ...

Comment: @PetterGreen In support of Nguyen Van Justonly Chi's reply, there are not too many quadratic surfaces. For this one, there is obviously a rotational symmetry in the x-y plane, so it makes sense to use polar coordinates for those, as above. Now, as for the rest, `r^2-z^2=1` is obviously a hyperbolic equation, so you can use cosh and sinh. (In physics this is nothing but the relativistic relation between energy and momentum, `E^2-p^2=m^2`, so there are zillions of such graphs around.)

Comment: @PetterGreen Fix for `very difficult (specially for 3D)`, I fail about it. Drawing this kind of surface is easy if you have its parametric equation, a `unbeautiful` picture (specially for 3D) if you only have its implicit equation with the package `smoothcontour3`.

Comment: Ok Now I will try to draw $4x^2+4y^2-z^2=1$ in 3D as I can. maybe impossible for me i will try >:

Comment: @PetterGreen You could use `real sign(real x){if (x<0) {return -1;} else {return 1;}}
triple f(pair t){return (sinh(t.y)*cos(t.x)/2,sinh(t.y)*sin(t.x)/2,sign(t.y)* cosh(t.y));}
` as a start.

Comment: @user230864 I don’t see like this function{4^x^2+4y^2-z^2=1}. Could you help me ?

Comment: @PetterGreen Well, if you add `(cosh(x) cos(y)/2)^2+(cosh(x) sin(y)/2)^2-(sinh(x))^2`, what do you get?

Comment: Where can I add?Here is my function 4x^2+4y^2-z^2=1

Comment: @user230864 Please kindly show me. Thank:)

Comment: @user230864 Please kindly. Show me how to draw this.